# hibernate criteria set projection groovy

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

I am using groovy:

this works well but I need it to have a field mapping coz it returns [[1,2], [2,2]]. I need it to be like this [[caseId :1, countId: 2], [caseId :2, countId: 2]]

```
def childNotes = ChildNote.withCriteria() {
            createAlias("caseInstance", "caseInstance")
            createAlias("caseInstance.caseTypeInstance", "caseTypeInstance")
            createAlias("childNoteEnteredBy", "childNoteEnteredBy")
           createAlias("assessmentTypeIdAssessmentType", "assessmentTypeIdAssessmentType")
           eq("caseTypeInstance.caseTypeDescrip", "Youth")
           eq("childNoteEnteredBy.id", ccuEmployeeId as Long)
           'in'("assessmentTypeIdAssessmentType.id", assesmentTypes)
           projections { groupProperty("caseInstance" ) 
                count("caseInstance")

               }

        }
```

this doesn't work

```
 projections { groupProperty("caseInstance" ) as "caseId"
                        count("caseInstance") as "caseCount"

                       }
```

I also tried the createcriteria and used this example on my code but the **"Projections"** in the Projections.property line is not recognized, even if I already imported the **org.hibernate.criterion.ProjectionList**

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Domestic.class, "cat")
.createAlias("kittens", "kit")
.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.property("cat.name"), "catName" )
    .add( Projections.property("kit.name"), "kitName" )caseInstance
)
.addOrder( Order.asc("catName") )
.addOrder( Order.asc("kitName") )
.list();
```

can anyone point me the right syntax for this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read every row of the result and create a Map for each one, or use an `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer`, which does that for you:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
```

Comment: is this for createcriteria instead of withcriteria? My problem with setProjections when using createCriteria is that it's not being recognized. tnx

Comment: It is for the Criteria instance that you're configuring, whatever the way you're doing it.

Comment: sorry how do I use this? I added it in my criteria and it resulted to [[:], [:]] . complete noob here. tnx

Comment: I added a class that implements it like in this blog http://javatechtricks.blogspot.com/ , but didn't solve it. it returns [[null:2], [null:1]]